# Custom class instantiates its superclass objects

Tags: ruby, inheritance, matrix

I'm working on a Grid class that inherits from `Matrix`:

```
class Grid < Matrix
  def self.[](x,y=x)
    if x.is_a? String
      ary = x.lines.map { |l| l.strip.split('|') }.map.with_index do |col,x|
        col.map.with_index { |cell,y| ::Cell.new x: x, y: y, alive: !!(cell =~ /O/i) }
      end
      super *ary
    else
      super *Array.new(y) { [::Cell.new(x: x, y: y, alive: [true,false].sample)] * x }
    end
  end
end
```

I can't seem to be able to overwrite `::initialize` since it's private. The above works but yields instances of `Matrix` class instead of my custom class, so I'm stuck. Realized my class wasn't instantiating when calling `to_s` and receiving `"Matrix[[X,O],[O,O]]"` stuff. What I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean `#initialize`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `::new` method in ruby, you define it via `#initialize`

When you call super it's calling `Matrix::[]` with the arguments provided.

Look at the [source code](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
def Matrix.[](*rows)
  Matrix.rows(rows, false)
end
```

You can try defining `Grid::rows` with your logic instead. Or just override `#initialize`

---

Incidentally this is poorly written, they should have done `rows(rows,false)` (without the Matrix) to prevent this very issue.

Comment: Made a typo, `initialize ` method can't be overridden for `Matrix` class for some reason. When subclassing classes like `Array` I can redefine `initialize ` and calling `super` with whichever arguments does the trick.

Comment: There are `new` methods all over the place.

Comment: @nicooga regardless of being unable to override `#initialize` did the rest of the answer help?

Comment: @DaveNewton: you don't define initializer functions in ruby with `def self.new` you do `def initialize`.

Comment: @Tal I am aware of that. Characterizing that as "There's no `::new`" is incorrect, since `new` is quite frequently overridden.

Comment: @nicooga if you look at the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-new) you'll see that instead of overriding the initialize method you should override the `rows` method.

Comment: The `[]` and `rows` methods are almost aliases, I can't see how that could make any difference, most importantly, I can't override `intialize`, and overriding any other constructor method instantiates `Matrix`.

Comment: The problem is that `Matrix::[]` calls `Matrix.rows` not `rows`. It's not aliasing it, it's actively calling the method on the `Matrix` class. Not `self`. So i bet if you change your code to override rows and never use `::[]` it'd work. Alternately you can monkeypatch matrix to fix the problem. `class Matrix; def self.[](*rows);rows(rows,false);end;end`